# Error while using classes and promise in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am calling class using following code

```
var user_ctx = new user();
user_ctx
    .set_email(req.body.email)
    .then(user_ctx.set_username(req.body.username))
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
```

and the class is defined as follows

```
function user () {
    this.user = {};
};

user.prototype.set_username = function (username) {
    return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
        this.user.username = username;
        fullfill();
    });
};

user.prototype.set_email = function (email) {
    return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
        var email_ctx = new email_lib(email);
        email_ctx
            .is_valid()
            .then(function() {
                this.user.email = email;
            })
            .then(fullfill)
            .catch(reject);
    });
};
```

the problem is that the `email` us not defined in user. i also tried the following

```
user.prototype.set_email = function (email) {
    return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
        var email_ctx = new email_lib(email);
        var that = this;
        email_ctx
            .is_valid()
            .then(function() {
                that.user.email = email;
            })
            .then(fullfill)
            .catch(reject);
    });
};
```

thereby referencing it using `that` inside callback function; but the email is still not being set. Already tried logging that the variable `email` is there in promise chain of `set_email` where am i going wrong with this ?

Comment: `return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
        this.user.username = username;
    });` - this is a promise that will never be anything but a pending Promise - this has no value whatsoever

Comment: @JaromandaX i forgot to add that `fullfill()` code to that block just to keep code short and to the point. the problem is with setting the value of email in `this.user` the setting of `username` is working fine which i verified by writing another method to print out the contents of same

Comment: well, you're also guilty of the classic promise anti-patterns - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: `.then(function() {
                this.user.email = email;
            })` check what `this`  is in this code

Comment: @JaromandaX its coming out to be undefined;

Comment: i usually go with `set_email.bind(this)` but the method in this case needs to take params with it

Comment: use an arrow function

Comment: Tried with arrow functions. Logging the output in next line inside the function gives proper result. but when i later print the object it does not print the whole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as expected, due to several errors / incorrect implementation:

1. You call `user_ctx.set_username` immediately, without waiting the promise will be resolved. Instead of `.then(user_ctx.set_username(req.body.username))` you must use: `.then(() => user_ctx.set_username(req.body.username))`.
2. You create Promise via constructor, when calling service `email_ctx` is already returns a promise.
3. You use wrong `this`. Inside the function `this` points to the parent function.

Correct implementation might look like this:

```
var user_ctx = new user();
user_ctx
    .set_email(req.body.email)
    .then(() => user_ctx.set_username(req.body.username))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

function user () {
    this.user = {};
};

user.prototype.set_email = function(email) {
    var self = this;
    var email_ctx = new email_lib(email);
    return email_ctx
        .is_valid()
        .then(function() {
           self.user.email = email;
        });
    });
};

user.prototype.set_username = function (username) {
    this.user.username = username;
};
```